# Why does inverting with respect to the incircle sends the circumcircle to the nine-point circle of the contact triangle?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles

Let $ABC$ be a triangle with incenter $I$ and $DEF$ is the contact triangle of $ABC$ (Edited, the previous definition of $D,E,F$ was wrong). Consider an inversion with respect to the incircle of $\triangle ABC$. Why does the circumcircle of $ABC$ maps to the nine point circle of $DEF$ by this inversion? I need to show that if $A^{*}$ ,$B^{*}$, $C^{*}$ are the images of $A,B,C$ then $A^{*}$ ,$B^{*}$, $C^{*}$ lie on the nine point circle of $DEF$, but why is that true?

Comment: Hint: The images of $A$, $B$, $C$ are three of the nine points.

Comment: @Blue This is excatly what I've written in the end, it is enough to show that. But why is that true?

Comment: @Blue oh, you mean that they are some of the "special" points? I tried to look for that as well, but I still didn't see why is it happening.

Comment: Right: I'm saying $A^\star$, $B^\star$, $C^\star$ are, specifically, three of the defining nine points of the nine-point circle of $\triangle DEF$. There are only limited options for what they could be ... midpoints, altitude-feet, orthocenter-vertex-midpoints. Draw an accurate figure (say, with [GeoGebra](http://geogebra.org)) and you'll see what they are. And/or if you think about, say, how inverses of points relate to tangent segments to the circle of inversion, the *why* may come to you.

Comment: @Blue Wait, I think I defined D,E,F incorrectly in the post. It should be the tangency points of the incircle with the sides of ABC, isn't it?

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't catch that earlier. ... Yes: If, as your question title indicates, the question is about the "contact triangle" of the incircle, then $D$, $E$, $F$ should be the points of tangency. That's the interpretation I was using when I gave my hints.

Comment: @Blue Yes, I got it now, using the fact that $A^{*}$ is the midpoint of the segment joining the tangency points from $A$ we get that $A^{*}$ is the midpoint of EF etc, so the question is solved. Thank you!

Comment: Congratulations! Write your solution as an answer (and accept it when you are able), so that we can up-vote your success. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will use the known fact that given an inversion $*$ with respect to a circle $\omega$, then for any point $A$ outside $\omega$, $A^{*}$ is the midpoint of the tangency points from $A$. Using this fact, we get that in our case $A^{*}$ is the midpoint of $EF$ (as $E,F$ are the tangency points from $A$ to the incircle). Similarly, $B^{*}$,$C^{*}$ are the midpoints of $DE,DF$ respectively. Therefore, by inverting with respect to the incircle, the circumcircle of $ABC$ maps to the circumcircle of $A^{*}B^{*}C^{*}$, which is the circle passing through the midpoints of $EF,DF,DE$ or in other words the nine-point circle of the triangle $DEF$.